# Protractor E2E : Enable screen capturing and "use fake ui" not working together in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, protractor, webrtc

I am trying to test an app which uses both camera and screen sharing as part of its functionalities.

The problem I am having right now in chrome is that chrome will not let me test both of these features together.

The flags I am currently using are :

--enable-usermedia-screen-capturing  (to allow screen sharing)

--use-fake-ui-for-media-stream (to tell chrome to use a fake camera so I can test camera streaming)

How can I test both these things in a place where I have no access to a physical camera? (web server somewhere in aws).